# How to Show your main “shell” that you use.? in UNIX

Tags: shell, shell-script

How to Show your main “shell” that you use.? in UNIX
is this command right
ps -p$$ or if there is a different way?

Comment: Do you mean your default shell or the one you are using at the moment? Do you mean UNIX specifically or on any UNIX-like system such as Linux?

Comment: yes  i mean UNIX  speciffically ,default shell or the onei am  are using at the momen

Answer (score 2):

`$$` is the current process.

`ps -p$$` therefore shows you your current process - which in this case, is your shell.

You can also `echo $SHELL`.

Or

```
getent passwd | grep ^`whoami`: | awk -F: '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: great help tahnk you

Comment: @Sobrique, I think you meant grep ^$( whoami ), and, minimally, neither the '^' nor the ':'  are not necessary although the carrot is useful.

Comment: @Daniel both are needed, what if you have a user called `foo`, one called `foobar` and one called `barfoo`. If you grep for `foo`, you'll get all three.

Comment: @terdon, that's true.  I wanted to point out the need to invoke whoami as a command, should have just edited the answer myself :).

Comment: @Daniel `whoami` is being invoked as a command. Note the backticks.

Comment: @terdon the backticks weren't there originally -- which is why I made the comment to Sobrique, who then added the backticks.  Notice, my comment to him used $( ) which is functionally equivalent in this instance.

Comment: They were, I'd just missed the fact that they're also formatting metacharacters :)

Answer (score 1):

To get your default shell, you can just print the `$SHELL` variable:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

While this is [not defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html), it is available on all shells I tested on (ash,bash,dash,fish,csh,ksh,tcsh and zsh).

If that command doesn't work on your environment, you can always look at `/etc/passwd`. For example, on a Linux system (probably UNIX as well, but I don't know), the shell of the user `foo` is given by the command:

```
grep '^foo:' /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f7
```

To get the shell you are currently running, you could use:

```
ps -p $$ | tail -n1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just gonna add to the other answers that if you want to test for a specific SHELL you can use the following:

- Bash: `echo $BASH`
- Ksh: `echo $KSH_VERSION`

Those variables will be set by the respective shell you're running.